# Bootstrap: center elements according to overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the minimal code for reproducing the 'issue':

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center">
  <h1>REALLYREALLYREALLYLONGWORDIT'SNOTOVERYET</h1>
  <button class="btn">REALLYLONGTEXTAGAINCANYOUEVENREADTHIS</a>
</div>
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akrzj7o9/).

Now, when the screen size is sufficiently large, it looks fine:

[image]

But if the screen size becomes small, it starts looking like this:

[image]

The text overflows; there is a scroll bar for it; but the button is still centered on the visible part of the screen, and not the entire 'view'.

I tried changing values of `overflow` style property but there is no effect. Really though, this doesn't seem to be a problem with the overflow, but rather the way the container 'boundaries' are defined. How would I go about 'fixing' this?

Comment: Have you tried any `@media` changes to the css?

Comment: Sorry, was not aware of `@media`. Will take a look.-

Comment: Yeah, `@media` is for resizing screens. There are a lot of examples in the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent div is a fluid container as the class name informs. That means, there is no `width` property dictating the dimension of that container. Also the `h1` text doesn't have any spaces, so the text can't break, preventing the content to center.
Thus the title overflows and the `button` gets center on the visible part of the window, which happens to be all the space filled by the `container-fluid` div.

Off the bat, I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Set a `min-width` or `width` property to the parent div.
2. Use `@media` queries to resize the text and/or elements on certain resolutions.
3. Use `float:left` on the parent div to force full width.

Comment: Yes setting `min-width` to a 'sufficiently large' value does seem to do the trick, but I'm not sure if it's the 'best' way to approach this.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a `div` to stretch if any of it's children overflow? Seems like that would be ideal.

Comment: On the variables css file on Bootstrap, you're supposed to set the `width` of the rows, which then solves these `min-width` issues.

Comment: Sure. See point 3. That will force the parent div to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Your text not contain space " ".
for all text which definitely need a space!!!

Comment: I was just trying to simulate an overflow. It could very well be a long word and a tiny screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use container as class  instead of container-fluid
    Look in this fiddle

```
[jsFiddle][http://jsfiddle.net/akrzj7o9/6/]

I think it can help to you
```

Reason: container fluid contains negative padding where as container does not have.

Comment: Make the text inside `h1` one word without spaces. It doesn't work.